# обработки ошибок в koa.js

Tags: node.js, koa.js

Использую: koa2(async/await)
Возможен ли такой вариант для обработки ошибок:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => { 
    try { 
        await next()
        if (ctx.status === 404) { 
            ctx.throw(404)
        }
    } catch (err) { 
        if (err.status === 404) {
            ctx.status = 404
            await ctx.render('404')
        } else { 
            console.log(err)
        }
    } 
})
```

Как еще можно обрабатывать ошибки?

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).